# Codeigniter adding the language to the url for SEO

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to add the short version of the language to url and get from the url to load the multi language file.

```
e.g www.example.com/ and www.example.com/en/ as default language and www.example.com/am/ for Amharic language.
```

I have the amharic and english folder and translation files in side the application/language. I simply want to add the /am/about and load the amharic translations  and /en/about or/about load the english. 
Codeigniter version 3.0.6